# How to get rigify outlines in armatures

Tags: rigging, armature

I've been rigging my own models and lately I see a lot of models with weird outlines instead of the normal bones I use.(Like the ones shown below) How do I make these?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can custom your bones. Create the new shape you want to see as bone, for example a circle. Then select your armature, go in *Object* or *Pose* mode, then *Properties* panel > *Bone* > *Viewport Display*, and select the object you've created. If you enable the *Wireframe* option you'll only see a wireframe object like in your picture.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's the answer. The image in the original post looks like a Rigify setup. When you hit Generate Rig with Rigify it creates a collection called Widgets that holds all of the shape objects for the rig.